# Obtain code window information based on cursor position using visual studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, envdte, vsix, vs-extensibility

Is there a way to obtain code window information based on cursor position using visual studio extension.

To be more clear:

If the cursor placed at line 10 in code window. Is there a way to obtain

1. Line Number using visual studio extensions
2. Code window text where cursor is placed using visual studio extensions

Any help on the above would be greatly appreciated.

Any sample code samples would of great help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My question is answered here. Please refer the link below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8e11df0d-07b2-4053-9f46-825dc28cd30a/obtain-code-window-information-based-on-cursor-position-using-visual-studio-extension?forum=vsx